# Drawing Image on a New Frame while still using Lissajou Curves in P5.js

Tags: javascript, variables, for-loop, waveform, p5.js

I'm working in p5.js and have created a lissajou curve and drawn a rabbit (in the spirit of Easter, I suppose). I'd like to have the rabbits head bounce along with the lissou curve, as if it's the star part of a (bouncing) shooting star. However, right now it's outputting a rabbit at every "point" so that a million rabbit heads are filling the screen. How do I make it so that it bounces along the screen leading the curve, rather than outputting a blurred stream of rabbit heads along with the curve?

I have a feeling that this has to do with the fact that the rabbit is maybe in the same loop as the lissajou curve. I've tried to create a separate function and lissajou curve for the rabbit, and playing around with some variables, but I am super new to this so I still need help with the logic. Thank you for any help! And if you could explain you answer a bit, I'd really, really appreciate it since I'm trying to learn as much as I can so that I can do this on my own next time. Thank you!

```
//Create a sketch that animates multiple shapes along Lissajous curves. Try animating color and size properties of the shapes using sin() and cos() as well.
var waveLengthOne = 25.0;
var waveLengthTwo = 200.0;
var pointCount = 0;
var angle = 2.0;
var amplitude = 130;
var xpos = 1; //playing around with a variable for x and y positions
var ypos = 1;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  background(233);
}

function draw() {
 // rabbit();

  if (pointCount > 2000) {
   noLoop();
  }
  noFill(); 
  strokeWeight(1);
  stroke(100);
  translate(width / 3, height / 3);
  beginShape();
  for (var i = 0; i < pointCount; i++) {
    angle = i / waveLengthOne * TWO_PI;
    var y = sin(angle) * amplitude;

    angle = i / waveLengthTwo * TWO_PI;
    var x = sin(angle) * amplitude;
    vertex(x, y);
  }
  endShape();
  pointCount++;

  // rabbit

    translate(x, y);
    noStroke()
    fill(255, 192, 203);
    ellipse(0, -60, 35, 40); // head
    fill(0);
    ellipse(-10, -65, 5, 5); //left eye
    ellipse(10, -65, 5, 5); //right eye
    ellipse(0, -55, 6, 5); //nose
    noFill()
    stroke(0);
    ellipse(0,-47, 5, 2); //mouth
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 193, 203); //ear color
    ellipse(-15, -90, 15, 40) //left ear
    ellipse(15, -90, 15, 40) // right ear
    stroke(0);
    line(-25, -60, 0, -55) // top left whisker
    line(-25, -50, 0, -55) // bottom left whisker
    line(25, -60, 0, -55) // top right whisker
    line(25,-50, 0, -55) // bottom right whisker


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the `background()` function from your `draw()` function to clear out any old frames. Otherwise you're just drawing on top of what's already there.

Calling the `background()` function is usually the first line of the `draw()` function in most Processing sketches.

```
function draw() {
   background(233);
   //rest of your code
```

Comment: Thanks, Kevin! However, when I do that nothing appears on the screen...it seems to cover/erase everything. Should I try putting it somewhere else?

Comment: @Claire I would check your JavaScript console for other errors. For example you declare `x` and `y` inside a loop, but then you use them outside that loop. They'll be out of scope then, so that will cause an error. You need to declare them before the loop so you can use them after the loop.

Comment: For some reason I had to refresh my code editor a couple of times and then it worked? Not sure what was happening there. Anyways, thanks so much for your help! Claire